# Click on index layout works only during list scrolling

Tags: android, listview, indexing, scroll

i created a list with an index on the right side, thanks to [IndexableListView](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView) files. Here is my activity:

```
public class FindByname extends Activity {
    private Database db = new Database(this);
    private IndexableListView mListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.indexable);

        SQLiteDatabase dbR = db.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
        list = createFullList(dbR);

        ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(this, R.layout.user_list_row, list);

        mListView = (IndexableListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    }

    private ArrayList<User> createFullList(SQLiteDatabase rw) {
        ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

        Cursor result = rw.rawQuery("SELECT _id, title, phone, city, category FROM users ORDER BY title ASC", null);
        while (result.moveToNext()) {
            list.add(new User(result.getString(0), result.getString(1), result.getString(2), result.getString(3), result.getString(4)));
        }
        result.close();
        return list;
    }

    private class ContentAdapter extends MyAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

        private String mSections = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        public ContentAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<User> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
            // If there is no item for current section, previous section will be selected
            for (int i = section; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (int j = 0; j < getCount(); j++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        // For numeric section
                        for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
                            if (StringMatcher.match(String.valueOf(getItem(j).getNome_user().charAt(0)), String.valueOf(k)))
                                return j;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (StringMatcher.match(String.valueOf(getItem(j).getNome_user().charAt(0)), String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i))))
                            return j;
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] getSections() {
            String[] sections = new String[mSections.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < mSections.length(); i++)
                sections[i] = String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i));
            return sections;
        }
    }
}
```

I get something like this:

[image]

The problem is that since my items are clickable the click on the index doesn't work. The letters on the index are clickable only during list scrolling! If i stop scrolling when i click on letters (before the disappearing of the index) it triggers the click on the list items, instead of the click on the index letters.

Here is MyAdapter class to handle click listener on list items:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutid;
    private List<User> data;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<User> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutid = textViewResourceId;
        data = objects;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public User getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutid, parent, false);

            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nameUser);
            holder.city = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cityUser);
            holder.rating = (RatingBar) row.findViewById(R.id.ratingUser);
            holder.distance = (TextView) row.findViewById(id.distanceKm);
            holder.category = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.catUser);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        User user = data.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(user.getNome_user());
        holder.city.setText(user.getComune());
        holder.rating.setRating(user.getVoto());
        holder.distance.setText(user.getDistanza());
        holder.category.setText(user.getCategory());

        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) holder.rating.getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.rgb(255, 215, 0), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                User merc = getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewUser.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", merc.getId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return row;
    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView city;
        RatingBar rating;
        TextView distance;
        TextView category;
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Sorry for my english

Comment: `since my items are clickable `. I do not see an onListItemClick() defined. How did you manage? Think you have to post MyAdapter class too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you are right. I edited my answer and i add MyAdapter class. Please check it out.

Comment: Ok. You edited your post. I see you set an OnClickListener for every row. Think you better don"t do that. Instead set one OnListItemClickListener for the whole listview in OnCreate(). Please try.

Comment: Do you mean onCreate() in FindByName classe, right? What object should i add OnListItemClickListener to? IndexableListView does not have it...

Comment: Nevermind, i did add setOnItemClickListener to mListView. Now how to trigger the selected item? Can you show me an example?

Comment: Indeed  in that Activity. mListView.setOnListItemClickListener(.........); should do it.

Comment: I add new comment while you posting. Please read above and thank you for your help.

Comment: Well show what you did first.

Comment: Ehm... i tried to copy what the listener that was in MyAdapter... but obviously it doesn't work and i do not how to trigger items positions

Comment: Where are you talking about? You should have added an mListView.setOnItemClickListener(....) in the onCreate of your Activity. And i asked you to show it.

Comment: Sorry for my english... i did this: http://pastebin.com/hSSmXg4v . Now i can't figure out how to access the position of the clicked item in the list...

Comment: Please add your code to your post here. You can use an extra code block for it as you did for the MyAdapter class. By the way: int arg2 is the position in the list. Comment the row click listener so it is not used.

Comment: I have already commented the row listener in MyAdapter. Now i want to see if your hint is the solution to my problem. I did see that arg2 is the position of the selected item in the list... but i cannot figure out how to access the related user :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in the IndexableListViewActivity of github.

```
  mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
        {
            Toast.makeText(IndexableListViewActivity.this,
               "position: " + position + "\n\n" + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }});
```

For your FindByName Activity it would be more like:

```
  mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
        {
         User user = list.get(position);

         Toast.makeText(FindByName.this, 
             "position: " + position + "\n\n" + user.getNome_user(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }});
```

Comment: I finally solved! Thank you for making me to figure out the right way to solve the problem. Anyway i used `User u = (User)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);` instead of `User user = list.get(position);`. Am i right?